# "Google Maps API Keyboard Shortcuts" pop up opens on "Enter" in Laravel Blade

Tags: api, window, maps

I have been using the same file for over a year and suddenly on my local environment, my Google Maps API keeps opening up a "Keyboard Shortcuts" pop up when hitting enter. Usual when hitting enter, my cursor moves to the next required input field in the form. I have made no changes to my code but I have updated Sublime Text, my Text Editor and it seems to support .blade.php files now.

How my JavaScript looked after the update:
[image]

I ended up fixing the code and here is my code currently:

My Form:


Client Address


Search Client Address

```
            </x-slot>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <label>Physical Address<span style="color: red"> *</span></label>
                    <input type="search" id="searchmap" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Address..." name="address">
                    <input hidden type="text" name="lat" id="lat" required>
                    <input hidden type="text" name="lng" id="lng" required>
                    <br>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div id="map-canvas"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end::Row -->
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <label>Address Comments</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" name="address_comments" id="address_comments" rows="3"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
        </x-card>
```

My JavaScript:

```
 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYKEY&libraries=places" type="text/javascript"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),{
                  center:{
                    lat: -26.18,
                    lng: 28.04
                  },
                  zoom:9
                  }); 
                  
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                  Position: {
                    lat: -26.18,
                    lng: 28.04
                  },
                  map: map,
                  draggable: true
                });
                var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(document.getElementById('searchmap'));
                google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox,'places_changed',function(){
                  var places = searchBox.getPlaces();
                  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
                  var i, place;
                  for(i=0; place=places[i];i++){
                    bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
                    marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location); //set marker position new...
                  }
                  map.fitBounds(bounds);
                  map.setZoom(18);
                  
                });
              google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'position_changed',function(){
                var lat = marker.getPosition().lat();
                var lng = marker.getPosition().lng();
                $('#lat').val(lat);
                $('#lng').val(lng);
              });
        </script>
```

The pop up window:
[image]

Comment: We have a similar issue since today. A form with a Google Maps is refreshed because the Enter takes over the submit event.

Comment: We fixed it by using the submit event of the form, adding a e.preventDefault there. We should've done that from the start. Legacy code was the issue here.

Comment: Thank you @Bergt! I'm looking into that now... Do you mind showing me a code example of how you did it?

Answer (score 4):

If you don't need actual keyboard shortcuts button to display, you could hide it by setting the control options for the google map instance by:

`keyboardShortcuts: false`

The documentation doesn't specifically show you this, but they do mention the control at: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem on an older project I have to fix issues on. The Google Maps container is part of a `<form>`. However, this `<form>` has no `action` and in JavaScript there was no listener attached to the `submit` event.

```
<form class="some-class">
    ...
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
    ...
    <a href="#" class="btn btn--primary js-send">Send</a>
</form>
```

The `<a>` has a `click` event attached to it, and will gather all data from the form and send it via ajax to an endpoint. There was also a `keyup` listener event where the "Enter" key was used to submit the data.

So this form breaks all kinds of rules

- no `action`, thus page refreshes if `submit` event is triggered and nothing will have happened
- the `<a>`-tag should have been a submit button, and the `<form>` should have a listener for the submit event
- `keyup` event should not be necessary, the form handles the enter key automatically
- the form shouldn't have been part of the form in the first place

The above breaks since a recent Maps change, where keyboard features were added. The Maps takes over the "Enter" key, instead showing the kayboard shortcuts of Maps.

We fixed this legacy code by changing the  tag in a  and attach a event listener to the form that listens for the `submit` event. We also removed the map out of the form, but this is not the cause of the issue.

Anyhow, another fine example of where native HTML element and JavaScript features should be used for what they are created for.

Answer (score 0):

A bit hacky but you can use:

```
[class*='-keyboard-shortcuts-dialog-view']{
    display:none;
}
```